# Do we have something like MATLAB fnval function in Python?

Tags: python, matlab, smoothing, spline

Using MATLAB csaps function I created a cubic polynomial and using MATLAB fnval function I did function evaluations. I am writing the same code in Python. I found the csaps function from the csaps library that gives me the same result, however, I cannot find anything in Python that does MATLAB's fnval job. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some python code using numpy and scipy that simulates the `fneval` example taken from the [MATLAB documentation here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/fnval.html). Basically, the scipy CubicSpline class can be called with the values to be evaluated at (see also the scipy [CubicSpline documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline.html#scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline)).

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import CubicSpline

x = np.array([0.074, 0.31, 0.38, 0.53, 0.57, 0.58, 0.59, 0.61, 0.65, 0.71, 0.81, 0.97])
y = np.array([0.91, 0.96, 0.77, 0.5, 0.5, 0.51, 0.51, 0.53, 0.57, 0.62, 0.61, 0.31])
# note: the original MATLAB example had the 0.61 value duplicated, which caused an error in the scipy interface and therefore removed here

cs = CubicSpline(x, y)
cs(0.5)
# array(0.5294082)

cs(np.arange(0, 1.01, 0.1))
# array([0.36518816, 1.02204653, 1.15788575, 0.98591757, 0.71915931, 0.5294082 , 0.5170693 , 0.61339552, 0.61721945, 0.48367111, 0.21564924])
```